# Regex get subdomain but only first part

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a few subdomains that all end start with `test` and end with `example.com`

I need to grab the text that is right `test`

**test.apple.example.com** --> `apple`

**test.banana.example.com** --> `banana`

**test.orange.pear.example.com** --> `orange`

It's possible that after the required text, there will just be `.example.com`, or there could be other parts of the url, like we see in the last example with `.pear.example.com` being the remaining url.

I need to only grab the **first** choice.

This is what I have come up with:

[image]

I need the capturing group to only be the first occurrence. In the last example it should only grab **orange**

Comment: You may use `^test\.([^.]+).*\.example.com$` in `re.findall`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
import re

strings = ['test.apple.example.com', 'test.banana.example.com', 'test.orange.pear.example.com']
for x in strings:
    print(re.search(r'(?<=test\.)(.*?)(?=\.)', x).group(0))

apple
banana
orange
```

#### Edit

As suggested by @Rivers, we can change above answer due `example.com`:

```
for x in strings:
    print(re.search(r'(?<=test\.)(.*?)(?=\..*?example\.com)', x).group(0))

apple
banana
orange
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I extend this to make sure the domain ends with `example.com` ?

Comment: `(?<=test\.)(.*?)(?=\..*?example\.com)`

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a capture group to match part after `test.`:

```sh
^test\.([^.]+).*\.example.com$
```

Use this regex in `re.findall`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PmqtLz/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `test\.`: Match `test.`
- `([^.]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `.`
- `.*\.example.com`: Match 0 or more of any characters followed by `.example.com`.
- `$`: End

**Code:**

```sh
>>> import re
>>> arr = ['test.apple.example.com', 'test.banana.example.com', 'test.orange.pear.example.com']
>>> rx = re.compile(r"^test\.([^.]+).*\.example.com$")
>>> for i in arr: print (rx.findall(i))
...
['apple']
['banana']
['orange']
```